# Using AChartEngine, can left axis grid be a different color than the right axis grid?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using AChartEngine to have two Y-Axis. The problem I'm having is that the two axis do not line up, and it is extremely confusing what line is for what axis. The 0 points don't even line up.

```
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setPointSize(14);


    renderer.setChartTitle( "Waves" );

    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabels( 10 );
    renderer.setYLabels( 10 );
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { vdiMin, vdiMax, netMin, netMax });
    renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { vdiMin, vdiMax, netMin, netMax });
    renderer.setZoomRate(1.05f);

    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(1, Color.WHITE);

    if( spinnerChoice == 0 ) {
        renderer.setYTitle("Diff Volts", 1);
    } else {
        renderer.setYTitle( "Current", 1 );
    }
    renderer.setYTitle( "Net Volts", 0 );
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 1);
```

Does anyone know a way to line up the two axis at 0, or draw the gridlines different colors?

Using `renderer.setAxesColor( Color.LTGRAY )`, I tried adjusting it to use the scaling number, but it did not work.

```
renderer.setAxesColor( Color.LTGRAY, 1 );
    or
renderer.setAxesColor( 1, Color.LTGRAY );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no way to have the separate Y-axis have different color grid lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can set some Y fixed ranges for both such as they line up. For instance:

```
renderer.setYAxisMin(0, 0);
renderer.setYAxisMax(10, 0);
renderer.setYAxisMin(0, 1);
renderer.setYAxisMax(100, 1);
```

For setting the grid color you need to call `renderer.setGridColor(color)`, but this has no support for multiple scales yet.

Comment: I tried this, but I'm assuming that you mean `setYAxisMin()`? Either way, I have tried both. It turns out now that I'm back today looking the 0's are lining up, but the left axis has 4 tick marks above 0 while the right axis only has 3. I have called `.setYLabels(10)`, but neither side show 10 labels and there is no parameter for multiple scales. Any ideas?

Comment: It was setY* indeed, I updated the answer. The setYLabels will set an approximate number of labels. The exact number is based on how the round values are determined.

Comment: OK, so my values range on one axis from [-180,180], and the other axis [-30,30]. I have `setYLabels(7)` for -180,-120,-60,0,60,120,180, and -30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30. However, only the second axis shows those labels. The first axis has tick marks only at -100, 0, 100. Is this a lost cause as of now since it doesn't support multiple scales?